# Specifying a specific version for shebanged scripts

Tags: perl, environment-variables, executable

If I invoke an executable script:

```
$ ./myscript
```

which has the following defintion at the top:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
```

and I have the following perls:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin | grep perl

-rwxr-xr-x.   2 root root        8416 2010-07-09 05:18 perl --> perl5.10.0
-rwxr-xr-x.   2 root root        8416 2010-07-09 05:18 perl5.10.0
-rwxr-xr-x.   2 root root        8416 2010-07-09 05:18 perl4.10.0
```

Is it possible to set some kind of environment variable (or any other means) to say that the perl version that is used will be `perl4.10.0`? I am looking for an answer that does not involve calling the script with the absolute path to a specific perl version, doesn't change the symbolic link, nor is language specific (meaning it would work for `/usr/bin/env ruby`, `/usr/bin/env python`, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - `#! /usr/bin/env perl` means "use the result from executing `/usr/bin/env perl` as the interpreter for this script", so you would need to impart extra knowledge to `env` (or whatever other script you chose to invoke in the command line) to know how to find executables according to the arguments you passed it.  `/usr/bin/env perl` doesn't look in your $PATH for files matching "perl*" - it looks for an executable file named *exactly* 'perl'.

Comment: Your explanation of what happens is a little off.  The kernel simply executes the command `/usr/bin/env perl SCRIPT REMAINING ARGS`.  It's `env` that searches the path for an executable named `perl` and executes `/path/to/perl SCRIPT REMAINING ARGS`.

Comment: I kind of figured there wasn't a solution to this. Just wanted to validate my assumption. Thank you for your contribution.